# Expansion tank is cold

Tags: water-circulating-heating

My old-style expansion tank is cold from top to bottom, but I hear boiling water in the pipes right above the gas furnace.  Is that normal?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We'll need more information; perhaps a picture of the tank and the surrounding pipes would help.

Comment: Thanks, Dan.  here is a photo of the expansion tank and the surrounding pipes.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to send a photo to you on Stackexchange.  Perhaps I can email it to you if you want to give me  your email address.

Comment: I'm sorry; I forgot that you need at least a reputation of 10 to post an image. I've up-voted your question, which brings you to 6. If you do a good job of fleshing out your question with more information you might get another vote, which would let you post that picture. Regardless, more information would be more likely to yield you a good answer.